# Ordernar por dois campos date

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
ID  |   PROMESSA    |   VENCIMENTO  
1   |   2019-01-04  |   2019-10-08
2   |   2019-01-03  |   2019-10-07
3   |   2019-01-02  |   2019-10-06
4   |   NULL        |   2019-10-05
5   |   NULL        |   2019-10-04
6   |   NULL        |   2019-10-03
7   |   NULL        |   2019-10-02
8   |   NULL        |   2019-10-01
```

Gostaria de selecionar os registros ordenando pelo campo `PROMESSA` crescente, depois pelo campo `VENCIMENTO` crescente.

Os dois campos são em formato `date`.

Tentei assim : `ORDER BY IF(PROMESSA IS NULL, 1, 0), PROMESSA ASC, VENCIMENTO ASC;`

Resultado esperado:

```
    ID  |   PROMESSA    |   VENCIMENTO
    3   |   2019-01-02  |   2019-10-06
    2   |   2019-01-03  |   2019-10-07
    1   |   2019-01-04  |   2019-10-08
    8   |   NULL        |   2019-10-01
    7   |   NULL        |   2019-10-02
    6   |   NULL        |   2019-10-03
    5   |   NULL        |   2019-10-04
    4   |   NULL        |   2019-10-05
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já tentou `ORDER BY COALESCE(PROMESSA, VENCIMENTO)`?

Comment: Caso as duas colunas possuam uma data válida, a sugestão anterior, não garante o requisito da pergunta: "Gostaria de selecionar os registros ordenando pelo campo PROMESSA crescente, depois pelo campo VENCIMENTO crescente"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua solução só precisa de um pequeno ajuste para gerar o resultado esperado. A solução consiste em alterar o IF.

**Solução 1:**

```
ORDER BY IF(PROMESSA IS NULL, 1, 0), PROMESSA ASC, VENCIMENTO ASC
```

Caso PROMESSA seja NULL então atribua 1, caso contrário atribua 0. Esta alteração irá garantir que os registos sem data PROMESSA sejam listados em último.

**Solução 2:**

Semelhante, mas mais concisa.

```
ORDER BY IF(PROMESSA IS NULL, '9999-12-31', PROMESSA), VENCIMENTO ASC
```

Caso PROMESSA seja NULL, a data '9999-12-31' será usada como default. Como esta é a data máxima, para o tipo DATE, registos nestas condições serão listados por último.

**Solução 3:**

Solução portável*, e baseada no comentário do Sorack, utilizando o COALESCE

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(PROMESSA, VENCIMENTO), VENCIMENTO
```

Note que se usar o COALESCE como em cima, tem que adicionar novamente a coluna VENCIMENTO. Desta forma garante que, caso as duas colunas possuam uma data válida, a ordenação irá considerar as duas datas e não apenas a primeira diferente de NULL.

*O COALESCE faz parte do padrão ANSI-92, e portanto existe em todos os sistemas de gestão de base de dados que implementem esta padrão (ou posterior).

Comment: @Sorack, como pode ter reparado, estava no meio de uma edição. Vou claro, referir o seu comentário, como fonte para a terceira sugestão.